# What is the correct Linux command of find, grep and sort?

Tags: shell

I am writing a command using find, grep and sort to display a sorted list of all files that contain 'some-text'.

I was unable to figure out the command.

Here is my attempt:

`$find . -type f |grep -l "some-text" | sort`

but it didn't work.

Comment: *it didn't worked* is not a problem description that is useful. How **specifically** did it not work?

Comment: reread your course work and look for the section on `xargs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use something like  [XARGS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) so that the content of each file passed through the pipe `|` is made available for grep.

XARGS: converts input from standard input into arguments to a command

In my case, I have files1,2,3 and they contain the word test. This will do it.

```
za:tmp za$ find . -type f | xargs grep -l "test" | sort
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
```

or

```
za:tmp za$ find . -type f | xargs grep -i "test" | sort
./file1.txt:some test string  
./file2.txt:some test string 
./file3.txt:some test string
```

Comment: no need to use xargs, use find's `-exec` option... and if you do need xargs(for ex: parallel processing), use `-0` option to avoid issues due to space and other special characters in filename

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Comment: I agree with @Sundeep's comment, in place of `xargs`, `exec` could have been used here for this case..

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in any unix:

find . -type f -exec sh -c 'grep "some text" {} /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1' \; -a -print 2> /dev/null|sort

A more optimized solution that works only with GNU-grep:

find . -type f -exec grep -Hq "some-text" {} \; -a -print  2> /dev/null|sort